# How to bind data of html form using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two files of php.First file is of seller status report.If I click on any record then a new tab(form) opens in new window.I have used window.open in js file.
Now in second form I have a html form.I want all field fill according to id.I am not familiar how to bind data in this case.

```
<?php
if 
(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"myquery");
if (isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['from']))
{
$a=$_POST['from'];
$b=$_POST['to'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"myquery'");
} 
else {
$result = mysqli_query($con,"myquery");
}
echo "<table id='example' class='display' border='1px' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
<thead style='background:cadetblue'>
<tr class='rowname'>
<th>Name</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>contact_no</th>
<th>state</th>
<th>city</th>
<th>TargetCity</th>
<th>ProjectName</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>PropertyDescription</th>
<th>PaymentPlanName</th>
<th>SaleTimeHorizon</th>
<th>PaytmentCompleted_Percentage</th>
<th>CreatedOn</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

echo"<tfoot style='display: table-header-group;'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>contact_no</th>
<th>state</th>
<th>city</th>
<th>TargetCity</th>
<th>ProjectName</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>PropertyDescription</th> 
<th>PaymentPlanName</th>
<th>SaleTimeHorizon</th>
<th>PaytmentCompleted_Percentage</th>
<th>CreatedOn</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>";
 echo "<tbody>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "<tr id='".$row['id']."'>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['contact_no'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['TargetCity'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['ProjectName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Size'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['PropertyDescription'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['PaymentPlanName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['SaleTimeHorizon'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['PaytmentCompleted_Percentage'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['CreatedOn'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo '<a href="download.php"><img src="images/Excel-Logo.jpg">
 </a>';
 echo"</tbody>";
 echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

The second file is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Buyer Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/master.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/profilepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datetime.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="full grey-bg btn-gryShdw pageHeader pos-r" id="header">
<div class="mr-r-15 mr-1-15" style="border-bottom:1px solid #ECECEC">
<div class="w100">
<div class="profilePic">
<img src="images/gravatar.jpg">
</div>
<div class="profileInfo w90" style="background-color:#1286f5">
<div class="f1 pos-r">
<div class="name ng-binding fl">Mayank</div>
<ul id="actions">   
<li id="service" class="w30 txt-ac">Service</li>
<li id="status" class="w30 txt-ac">Status<br>Open</br></li>
<li id="user" class="w40 txt-ac">User Created On
<div class="date1">12 August</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<div id="main" class="fl" style="width:100%">
<div id="content" class="pad5 fl mr-t5 " style="margin-bottom:25px;word-wrap:break-word      ;width:20%;">
<form class="pad-l5 mr-t10 ">
           <div id="name">Name</div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Email</div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Contact Number</div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>City</div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    </form></div>
    <div id="maindropdown" class="mr-t5 fl pad5" style="width:40%">
    <div id="dropstatus" class="mr-t5 fl pad5">
    <span>Status</span><br>
    <select>
        <option value="Gurgaon">Open</option>
        <option value="Noida">Pending For Request</option>
        <option value="Gurgaon">Close</option>
    </select> 
    </div>
    <div id="dropdownsub" class="mr-t5 fl pad5">
        <span>SubStatus</span><br>
        <select style="width:255px">
            <option value="Not Known">Not Known</option>
            <option value="Understood">Understood</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="txtarea" class="mr-t10 pad-t50">Description/Notes<br>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="50" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="nextaction" class="mr-t6 fl pad5" style="width:35%">Next Action<br>
    <div id=nextactiontxt class="mr-t5 fl pad5">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="55"></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="mr-t6 fl pad5 mr-t30">Next Action Date<br>
        <input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="mr-t6 fl pad5 mr-t30">
        <span>Next Action Responsible</span><br>
        <select style="width:170px">
       <option value="name1">Rohit Rahav</option>
       <option value="name2">Vivek Aggarwal</option>
       <option value="name3">Hitesh Singla</option>
       <option value="name4">Soni</option>
       <option value="name1">Mayank Vashist</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","realitycheck");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
   }
   if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id,CONCAT_WS(' ', u.firstname,u.lastname) AS  Name
   from p_sellservices p left join users u
   on p.UserId=u.id left join rc_project pt on p.ProjectId=pt.ProjectId left join   p_paymentplan pp on
   p.PaymentPlanId=pp.PaymentPlanId left join rc_location lc on    p.LocationId=lc.LocationId"))) {
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
   }
   if (!$stmt->execute()) {
   echo "Execute failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
   }
   $out_id = NULL;
   $out_Name = NULL;
   if (!$stmt->bind_result($out_id, $out_Name)) {
   echo "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
   }
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   echo'<input type="text" id="name">';
   }
   ?>
```

script of window.open is here

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
     "pageLength": 100

  } );

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $("#example tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
        .on( 'change', function () {
            var val = $(this).val();

            table.column( i )
                .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                .draw();
        } );

    table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    } );
    } );

   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable(); 
   $('#example tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    window.open("new.php?uid="+id);
    //alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
   } );
   } );

   } );
```

Comment: where you written new window script?

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using different jquery version at one time? That could cause errors because of changing functions from version to version.

For your Problem, you could use AJAX to send your request to your PHP-File and sending your result to Javascript to fill your HTML-Container dynamically.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP